# How to counteract Before-trigger called twice on update for 'insert ... on conflict'?

Tags: postgresql

I've defined a BEFORE-trigger which does a couple of things:

1. adapt the current row to be saved by adding some calculated data
2. conditionally write some changes to a different table.

Although I'm aware that it's idiomatic to do `conditionally write some changes to a different table` in an AFTER-trigger instead of a BEFORE-trigger, it seems pretty much impossible to extract the logic of 1. and 2.

So given this, I'm having a bit of a problem:

I'm doing a `insert on conflict`, which results in row-updates triggering the BEFORE-trigger twice: once for an insert, and once for an update. (i.e.: PG correctly raises an 'id already exists exception', but this happens AFTER the before-trigger is executed)

This causes some of the logic in the BEFORE-trigger, such as writing changes, twice which is obviously wrong.

How to counteract this?

Although not very elegant I can imagine manually throwing an 'id already exists' exception in the BEFORE-trigger when an already existing row enters the trigger with state `TG_OP = 'INSERT'`. This would short-circuit the first trigger, and let PG take care of the rest: on conflict is raised, which causes update to happen.

However, I couldn't get this to work. Is it even possible to raise an exception manually, which is picked up by 'insert.. on conflict'?

Any alternatives?

Comment: You can't trigger `on conflict` like that. You could check in your `before insert` if in table exists row that will conflict with incoming data and either let update trigger do whatever it does (by doing nothing else in insert) or assume that update will not fire and do your computing in insert trigger. But that is additional `select` on table. Why can't those triggers be AFTER? AFTER INSERT won't trigger if conflict is detected.

Comment: because an AFTER trigger can't update the current row which is what I need as well. (see point 1.) It's a tangled mess I know. I probably just go ahead and do a select before deciding to do a insert of update in client-side code as you suggested.

Comment: *Although not very elegant I can imagine manually throwing an 'id already exists' exception in the BEFORE-trigger when an already existing row enters the trigger with state TG_OP = 'INSERT'* -- this would be not just the opposite of elegant, but most probably wrong too. The `UPSERT` functionality exists because there is *no other way* to ensure the atomic insertions (which cannot fail) over`UNIQUE` constraint(s)/index(es). (Except OFC the original retry loop, but that has its own flaws.) Rolling your own solution to this problem (ie. doing a manual `EXISTS` check) always the wrong solution ...

Comment: ... *Although I'm aware that it's idiomatic to do conditionally write some changes to a different table in an AFTER-trigger instead of a BEFORE-trigger* -- you are right here, and the solution seems obvious; that's why I'm not sure why didn't you think of that already: Use a `BEFORE` trigger for 1) and use a separate `AFTER` trigger for 2).

Comment: @pozs: it's difficult to separate the code in a before and after-trigger. However, given that there's probably no good alternative I think I should revisit this route. Thanks

Comment: This is off topic, but I couldn't help laughing when I read the first line of your question.

Comment: Hehe. Learned how to correctly spell that idiom today. Thanks for pointing it out. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can introduce a unique constraint on the second table that detects when the same data are entered twice. Then you could use `INSERT ... ON CONFLICT ... DO NOTHING` on the second table.

Answer (score 0):

You could use writeable CTE, I think this is PostgreSQL only extension. It can emulate UPSERT in a way.

Example:

```
CREATE TABLE trigger_table (id int, column1 text, column2 int);

INSERT INTO trigger_table VALUES (13, 'test2', 5);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION trigger_fkey()
 RETURNS trigger
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
BEGIN
raise exception 'test';
END;
$function$;

CREATE TRIGGER asdf BEFORE INSERT
   ON trigger_table FOR EACH ROW
   EXECUTE PROCEDURE trigger_fkey();

--works, update is done, insert not
WITH cte AS (UPDATE trigger_table SET column1 = 'test1', column2 = 1 
              WHERE id = 13 RETURNING id)
INSERT INTO trigger_table (id, column1, column2)
SELECT id, column1, column2
  FROM (VALUES (13, 'test1', 1)) AS b(id, column1, column2)
 WHERE id NOT IN(SELECT id FROM cte);

--after this before insert trigger will fire (on above insert) and exception is thrown
DELETE FROM trigger_table WHERE id = 13;
```

Comment: While this variant is not vulnerable to lost updates (like most ad-hoc versions of the `UPSERT`), it still requires a re-try loop. Without that [it can throw unique violation errors](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/78510/why-is-cte-open-to-lost-updates) under concurrent load.